# How to set the zoom factor in D3.js v.4.x?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js

I have a svg where I have implemented zooming via D3.js.
I am not satisfied with the zoom factor when using the mousewheel.
How can I adjust the zoom factor?

I made a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qk03mq10/6/) with an example of how I implemeted the zooming.

I thought I need something like this but it is wrong:

```
zoom.scaleBy()
```

I am trying to make my problem a bit clearer:

I want to set a factor, that acts as the zoom factor for one mousewheel revolution.
Illustration with pictures:

The SVG without zoom:
[image: Normal SVG]

After one mousewheel revolution:
[image: After one mousewheel revolution.]

What I would like to have after one mousewhell revolution:
[image: But I want some steps in between (like that)]

I know how this worked in older versions of D3.js but can someone help me with the current version?

Comment: If you are looking for some way to zoom programmatic ally, then you need to do like this `zoom.scaleBy(d3.select("svg"),0.08);` but on each scroll up down you need to calculate the new k value that currently is 0.08. https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/z94kt8hn/

Comment: Ok with your comment I figured out, that `zoom.ScaleBy()` is the worng way.

Comment: I want to set a factor for the zooming, basically I want my svg to not zoom so much per mousewheel revolution.

Comment: Going through the docs I don't see any direct way to set the factor, maybe you need to do it programmatically... or you need to see the source code how it is done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are very close in your JS Fiddle!

The crux of the issue here is that the scaling factor `k` is automatically updated when the event callback is called. The goal here is when we change from the previous k (`old_k`) to the new k, we need to scale the change, `delta`, and reapply it to get the new k value.

So the code changes to do this are as follows...

1. keep track of the old k value

   ```
   var old_k = 1;
   ```
2. calculate the delta k

   ```
   var delta = d3.event.transform.k - old_k
   ```
3. update with transform **with scaled delta!**

   ```
   d3.event.transform.k = old_k + zoomFactor*delta
   ```
4. reapply transform

   ```
   svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
   ```
5. save new k for the next event

   ```
   old_k = d3.event.transform.k
   ```

Play around with `var zoomFactor = .7;` to see that it works.

```js
console.clear()
//movement and controls
var stepLR = 30;
var controller;
var speed = 0.007;

//pendulum vertical
var cx = 609, cy = 0;
var radius = 350; // cm
var g = 981; // cm/s^2
var angle = Math.PI/8; // radians
var vel = 0; // cm/s
var dx = 0.02; // s
var acc, vel, penx, peny;

//svg and d3.js
var sphere;
var string;
var string2;
var sphere2;

//timing
var start;

var old_k = 1;
var zoomFactor = .7;

$( document ).ready(function() {
  start = (new Date()).getTime(); //start time on page load

  var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", '100%')
            .attr("height", '600px')
            .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
            var delta = d3.event.transform.k - old_k
            d3.event.transform.k = old_k + zoomFactor*delta
            svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
            old_k = d3.event.transform.k
        }))
        .append("g");

            var viewport = svg.append('g')

            var layer1 = viewport.append('g');
            var layer2 = viewport.append('g');

            sphere = layer2.append("circle")
                         .attr("cx", 30)
                         .attr("cy", 30)
                         .attr("r", 20)
                         .attr('fill', '#FF0000');

            string = layer1.append("rect")
                          .attr("x", 27)
                          .attr("y", 0)
                          .attr("width", 6)
                          .attr("height", 10);

            //The vertical pendulum
            sphere2 = layer2.append("circle")
                         .attr("cx", 609)
                         .attr("cy", 300)
                         .attr("r", 20)
                         .attr('fill', '#FF0000');

            string2 = layer1.append("line")
                        .attr("x1", 609.5)
                        .attr("y1", 0)
                        .attr("x2", 609.5)
                        .attr("y2", 310)
                        .attr("stroke-width", 4)
                        .attr("stroke", "black");

            var roof = layer1.append("rect")
                          .attr("x", -100000)
                          .attr("y", -60)
                          .attr("height", 55)
                          .attr("width", 200000)
                          .attr('fill', 'url(#diagonal-stripe-3)');
                          
            var border = layer1.append("rect")
                          .attr("x", -100000)
                          .attr("y", -10)
                          .attr("height", 10)
                          .attr("width", 200000)
                          .attr('fill', '#000000');




    controller = setInterval(controller, 30);  //start controller
});

function controller(){

  //horizontal pendulum
  sphere.attr('cy', Math.sin(start-(new Date()).getTime()/400-(Math.PI/4))*310+350);
  string.attr('height', Math.sin(start-(new Date()).getTime()/400-(Math.PI/4))*310+337);
  string.attr('width', Math.sin((start-(new Date()).getTime()/400-(Math.PI/4))-Math.PI)*3+6);
  string.attr('x', Math.sin((start-(new Date()).getTime()/400-(Math.PI/4)))*1.5-3+stepLR);

  //vertical pendulum
  acc = g * Math.cos(angle) * dx;
    vel += acc * dx;
    angle += vel * dx;
    setPenPos();


  document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    if([e.keyCode] == 37){
      left();
    }
    if([e.keyCode] == 39){
      right();
    }
  });
}

function left(){
  stepLR=stepLR-speed;
  sphere.attr('cx', stepLR);
  string.attr('x', stepLR);
}

function right(){
  stepLR=stepLR+speed;
  sphere.attr('cx', stepLR);
  string.attr('x', stepLR);
}

function setPenPos(){
    penx = cx + radius * Math.cos(angle);
    peny = cy + radius * Math.sin(angle);
    string2.attr("x2", penx);
    string2.attr("y2", peny);
    sphere2.attr("cx", penx);
    sphere2.attr("cy", peny);
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>

<svg height="10" width="10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"> <defs> <pattern id="diagonal-stripe-3" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="10" height="10"> <image xlink:href="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0naHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmcnIHdpZHRoPScxMCcgaGVpZ2h0PScxMCc+CiAgPHJlY3Qgd2lkdGg9JzEwJyBoZWlnaHQ9JzEwJyBmaWxsPSd3aGl0ZScvPgogIDxwYXRoIGQ9J00tMSwxIGwyLC0yCiAgICAgICAgICAgTTAsMTAgbDEwLC0xMAogICAgICAgICAgIE05LDExIGwyLC0yJyBzdHJva2U9J2JsYWNrJyBzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg9JzMnLz4KPC9zdmc+" x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10"> </image> </pattern> </defs> </svg>
```

Comment: Wow this looks really good, I will check tommorow and then Most likely donate the bounty

Comment: @frankenapps If this answer worked for you don't forget to mark it as an accepted answer! :)